# FontForge - How to add names to letters

Tags: fontforge

I would like to add text labels to my letters in FontForge, so I can refer to them by name in HTML as opposed to the actual letter or symbol. For example, the Google Material Design Font has many symbols, and you can refer to them by either a text label (cloud_queue), or a entity code (). The little material cloud icon is like this:

```
<i class="material-icons">cloud_queue</i>
or (for IE9 or below)
<i class="material-icons">&#xE2C2;</i>
```

How do you add a text label, such as cloud_queue, for a letter in FontForge?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The Material Design font achieved this using [ligatures](https://fontforge.github.io/editexample4.html#ligature).
To do this in your own font, first add an unencoded glyph to your font (or use a code point in the Unicode private use area, if you're using unicode encoding), then change its name to c_l_o_u_d_underscore_q_u_e_u_e. This tells FontForge that you intend the glyph to be a ligature that should be substituted whenever those letters appear in that order.